# Deserialize an Object C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I have the following json:

```
{
    "coord":{"lon":-88.92,"lat":44.46},
    "weather":[{"id":600,"main":"Snow","description":"light snow","icon":"13d"}],
    "main":{"temp":271.72,"pressure":1009,"humidity":73,"temp_min":269.15,"temp_max":273.15},
    "name":"XXXXX",
}
```

and I'm trying to deserialize in C# using this classes:

```
public class weatherClass
{

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("main")]
    public Info Main { get; set;}

    [JsonProperty("weather")]
    public List<InfoWeather> Weather { get; set; }
}

public class Info{
    public string temp { get; set;}
    public string pressure { get; set;}
}

public class InfoWeather {
    public string description { get; set;}
    public string main { get; set;}
}
```

I can acces to temp and pressure from Info Class. But I'm having problems with InfoWeather. It doesn't return anything:

```
weatherResult.Text = string.Format("The city is: {0} and the description is: {1}", weatherlass.Name, weatherlass.Weather);
```

If I use weatherlass.Weather.description

[image]

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] that shows your problem. Or another way of looking at it is that I should be able to copy and paste your code into VS or LINQPad and run it.

Comment: Here my problem: `weatherResult.Text = string.Format("The city is: {0} and the description is: {1}", weatherlass.Name, weatherlass.Weather); ` [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zv8zr2aop2vgs1/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-02%20at%2022.03.16.png?dl=0) if I use `weatherlass.Weather.description`. It returns error!

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the extra text and the image - don't link to the image externally, embed in the question instead - and can please put in the code that you use to deserialize? You need to make a copy-and-paste example in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*Change your class definitions to use proper case names then use the camel case converter provide by newtonsoft*/

public class WeatherClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Info Main { get; set; }
    public List<InfoWeather> Weather { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
    public string Temp { get; set; }
    public string Pressure { get; set; }
}

public class InfoWeather
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Main { get; set; }
}

var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
var weatherClass = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherClass>(json, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

Comment: Thanks @Vincent but I still having the same problem: [Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bpc4xz3hoqefivo/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-02%20at%2022.21.20.png?dl=0)

Comment: Then it is not a serialization problem as I ran it here and it works perfectly  Your Weather object is a List.  Try weatherClass.Weather[0].Description

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks. That was I needed :)